# Symfony2 associative array in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i have entity `languages` with format

```
id; name

en; English

pl; Polish

etc...
```

And I have some Entity `translations`, that in one column has an associative array:
{pl: "Some txt in PL", en: "Some txt in EN",...}

Everything is almost perfect, but i don't know how to create an form for editing such a thing :D I tried almost everything.

`Translation.orm.yml`:

```
...
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        value:
            type: array
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new Entity you must prepare your array in Controller ( before creating form). Something like that:

```
$value = array('en' => 'here en', 'pl' => 'here pl');
$translation->setValue($value);
$form = $this->createForm(new TranslationType()...
```

In Your FormType:

```
 $builder->add('value', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'options' => array(
            'required'  => true,
        ),
     )
 );
```

That's all.
If you have `{{ form_rest(form) }}` in your twig,  you'll see two additional fields for translations in your form and it will be work.
Additional information about collection field type is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Comment: Okey, that seems fine, but i want to have possibility to edit content in this 'array', and your solution give me only possibility to choose options?

Comment: Each element of array will be editable in your form without any additional work.